# How do I get the current user in Perl in a portable way?

Tags: perl, portability

How does one get the current user in a portable way?

This seems like an FAQ but [perlport](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlport.html) doesn't speak about it, maybe because some odd systems don't have the concept of "user" to being with? However, let's stick to *nix and Windows.

`getpwuid($>)` is not implemented on Windows.

`$ENV{USER} || $ENV{USERNAME}` seems finicky.

http://search.cpan.org didn't turn up much.

Comment: is this a CGI script or a scriplication (script app)?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[getlogin](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/getlogin.html):

> This implements the C library function of the same name, which on most systems returns the current login from /etc/utmp, if any.  If null, use "getpwuid".
>
> ```
> $login = getlogin || getpwuid($<) || "Kilroy";
> ```
>
> Do not consider "getlogin" for authentication: it is not as secure as "getpwuid".

You can also try ||-ing this with [POSIX::cuserid](http://perldoc.perl.org/POSIX.html#cuserid)() and [Win32::LoginName](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Win32#Win32::LoginName())().

Comment: If you have switched users with su, getlogin will return the original user, something that would be an unpleasant surprise to me as a user; just use getpwuid for posixy systems and Win32::LoginName for windows.

Comment: @ysth: good to know. I expect this is what the docs were alluding to in "Do not consider..for authentication".

Answer (score 4):

[Win32::LoginName()](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Win32/Win32.pm#Win32::LoginName%28%29) can be used on Windows to retrieve the user name (without the domain name, so it may be ambiguous):

```
use Win32;
my $username = Win32::LoginName;
```

[Win32::pwent](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Win32/Win32.pm#Win32::LoginName%28%29) implements getpwuid() and other features to query the user database. Unfortunately, it failed to install on my StrawberryPerl 5.12.