# How is $< handled in Perl for Windows?

Tags: perl

I am working on a Perl script where it checks for root access, at the beginning of execution.

```
if ($< != 0) {
  print "You need to be root";
  die "  ";
}
```

How is the `$<` evaluated in Windows? I searched google and here, but could not find an answer.

The closest I got was in [perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html). It has some descriptions of special variable handling in Windows, but not for this case.

> $<
>
> The real uid of this process. (Mnemonic: it's the uid you came from, if you're running setuid.) You can change both the real uid and the effective uid at the same time by using POSIX::setuid(). Since changes to $< require a system call, check $! after a change attempt to detect any possible errors.

Comment: Have you tried it? That's probably the best way to get an idea of what `$<` will do in Windows.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get the current user in Perl in a portable way?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3526420/how-do-i-get-the-current-user-in-perl-in-a-portable-way) -- assuming you need to verify what user is running the script.

Comment: Opps. Yeah forgot to say, it always seems to match zero on my Windows XP SP3 running "Strawberry" PERL.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On my Win7 box, `$<` and `$>` always return 0, regardless of whether I'm running as an Administrator, elevated Administrator, or regular user. I think Perl just punts on that because user IDs on Windows cannot be expressed simply as integers, so it doesn't even try.

Indeed, here's the [source code](http://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git/blob/HEAD:/win32/win32.c) (line 1073):

```
/* Ownership
 *
 * Just pretend that everyone is a superuser. NT will let us know if
 * we don\'t really have permission to do something.
 */

#define ROOT_UID    ((uid_t)0)
#define ROOT_GID    ((gid_t)0)

uid_t
getuid(void)
{
    return ROOT_UID;
}

uid_t
geteuid(void)
{
    return ROOT_UID;
}

gid_t
getgid(void)
{
    return ROOT_GID;
}

gid_t
getegid(void)
{
    return ROOT_GID;
}

int
setuid(uid_t auid)
{
    return (auid == ROOT_UID ? 0 : -1);
}

int
setgid(gid_t agid)
{
    return (agid == ROOT_GID ? 0 : -1);
}
```