# How to get system user full name on Windows in Perl?

Tags: perl

I have been using User::pwent to get the full name of the system user in Perl:

```
require User::pwent;
my $full_name = (User::pwent::getpwnam(getlogin)->gecos)[0];
```

However, `getpwnam` is not implemented in Windows Perl. What's the alternative to get the user's full name on Windows? Is it available?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get the current user in Perl in a portable way?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3526420/how-do-i-get-the-current-user-in-perl-in-a-portable-way)

Comment: @sean-bright No, that question just covers the login name, not the user's full name. That is, it gives me "sean-bright" but I want "Sean Bright".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Poked around, best thing I could find is to use [`Win32API::Net::GetUserInfo()`](https://metacpan.org/module/Win32API%3a%3aNet#UserGetInfo-server-user-level-hash-):

```
require Win32API::Net;
Win32API::Net::UserGetInfo( '', $self->sysuser, 10, my $info = {} );
my $full_name = $info->{fullName};
```

Need to get it running on a few Windows boxes though, to make sure it works.

---

**Update:** Confirmed to work with user info level 10:

```
> perl -MWin32API::Net -E "Win32API::Net::UserGetInfo('',Win32::LoginName(), 10, my $info = {} ); say $info->{fullName}"
Bartholomew Simpson
```

Not sure why 1011 does not work [as documented](https://metacpan.org/module/Win32API%3a%3aNet#USER-INFO-LEVELS), but this is good enough for me.

Comment: If I leave the first parameter of `UserGetInfo` to be an empty string, I don't get the info. However if I use `$ENV{LOGONSERVER}`, your example works for me.

Comment: You mean `Win32API::Net::UserGetInfo( $ENV{LOGONSERVER}, Win32::LoginName(), 10, my $info = {} );`? That seems odd.

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. I don't understand the details, but maybe it has something to do with the company network I'm in.